# Calculate rolling average of a measure based on certain condition from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, window-functions, lateral-join

Below is the given table.

| date | id1 | id2 | fact | boolean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | i1 | l1 | 100 | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 | i1 | l1 | 10 | 1 |
| 2022-01-03 | i1 | l1 | 110 | 0 |
| 2022-01-04 | i1 | l1 | 70 | 0 |
| 2022-01-05 | i1 | l1 | 20 | 1 |
| 2022-01-05 | i1 | l1 | 30 | 1 |
| 2022-01-06 | i1 | l1 | 40 | 0 |
| 2022-01-07 | i1 | l1 | 50 | 0 |
| 2022-01-08 | i1 | l1 | 70 | 0 |
| 2022-01-09 | i1 | l1 | 100 | 1 |
| 2022-01-09 | i1 | l1 | 10 | 1 |
| 2022-01-10 | i1 | l1 | 200 | 0 |

Expected outcome for rolling average:

| date | id1 | id2 | fact | boolean | rolling_avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | i1 | l1 | 100 | 0 |  |
| 2022-01-02 | i1 | l1 | 10 | 1 | 100 |
| 2022-01-03 | i1 | l1 | 110 | 0 |  |
| 2022-01-04 | i1 | l1 | 70 | 0 |  |
| 2022-01-05 | i1 | l1 | 20 | 1 | 90 |
| 2022-01-05 | i1 | l1 | 30 | 1 | 90 |
| 2022-01-06 | i1 | l1 | 40 | 0 |  |
| 2022-01-07 | i1 | l1 | 50 | 0 |  |
| 2022-01-08 | i1 | l1 | 70 | 0 |  |
| 2022-01-09 | i1 | l1 | 100 | 1 | 53.33 |
| 2022-01-09 | i1 | l1 | 10 | 1 | 53.33 |
| 2022-01-10 | i1 | l1 | 200 | 0 |  |

Rolling avg of 'fact' column for preceding 3 days required only for rows where boolean = 1 and while calculating the average consider only those values where boolean is 0.

Example1: for row 5, preceding 3 days are 4, 3 and 2 where boolean is 0 for 4 and 3. Hence (110+70/2) = 90

Example2: for row 9, preceding 3 days are 8, 7 and 6 where all have boolean = 0. Hence (70+50+40/3) = 53.33

I've tried doing

```
AVG(expression) OVER (PARTITION BY id1, id2 
                      ORDER BY date DESC 
                      ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as rolling_avg
```

However the result I got didn't match the required outcome.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dates may have gaps, then I would recommend a lateral join:

```
select t.*, a.*
from mytable t
outer apply (
    select avg(t1.fact) rolling_avg
    from mytable t1
    where t.boolean = 1
        and t1.id1 = t.id1 and t1.id2 = t.id2 
        and t1.date >= dateadd(day, -3, t.date) and t1.date < t.date
        and t1.boolean = 0
) a
```

The subquery selects rows that belong to the same ids over the 3 previous days and computes the average fact, with respect to the boolean flag of the current and previous rows.

If there is always one and only one fact row per date for a given tuple of ids, then window functions with a row frame are relevant (and more efficient):

```
select t.*, 
    case when boolean = 1 then
        avg(case when boolean = 0 then fact end) over(
            partition by id1, id2 
            order by date
            rows between 3 preceding and 1 preceding
        ) 
    end rolling_avg
from mytable t
```

Comment: I'm able to get the rolling avg value correctly using the window functions however I have more than 1 value for 'fact' column for combination of all ids and boolean =1 condition. In this case, Window function populates the rolling avg only for 1 row. Is there a way to populate it for other rows as well? 

id1, id2, fact, boolean, rolling_avg
1      2     100    1                100
1      2       10    1                100

Comment: Current:
| date | id1 | id2 | fact | boolean| 
| ---- | --- | --- | ---- | -------| 
|1     | 2   |  100  |  1     |       100|
|1     | 2   |    10   | 1      |            |

Expected:
| date | id1 | id2 | fact | boolean| 
| ---- | --- | --- | ---- | -------| 
|1     | 2   |  100  |  1     |       100|
|1     | 2   |    10   | 1      |      100|

Comment: Edited the original table to reflect this

Comment: @MaheshShankar: I understand. This falls in the limitation that I expressed like so in my answer: *If there is always one and only one fact row per date for a given tuple of ids, ...* If that's not the case, then use the other solution, which works regardless: https://dbfiddle.uk/asHc5qRx